Proxy param not taken into account by SeleniumBase in uc mode
I'm trying to use SeleniumBase on uc mode with a proxy with auth, but the IP is not changing. I tried 3 different proxy services (Oxylabs, Webshare and IPRoyal). Please help.
I just updated my SeleniumBase version (pip in Anaconda env). Using Windows server.
Thanks !!
from seleniumbase import Driver

proxy = "username:password@pr.oxylabs.io:7777"
''' Also tried these:
proxy = "p.webshare.io:9999" # I tried this after setting IP authentication in Webshare
proxy = "username:password@geo.iproyal.com:11201"
proxy = "username:password@p.webshare.io:80"
'''

driver = Driver(uc=True, proxy=proxy)
''' Also tried these:
driver = Driver(uc=True, proxy=proxy, use_wire=True, wire=True)
driver = Driver(uc=True, proxy=proxy, use_wire=True, wire=True, browser='firefox')
driver = Driver(uc=True, proxy=proxy, browser='firefox')
'''
driver.get("https://pixelscan.net/")
driver.sleep(10)
driver.quit()


I forgot to disable the Network Protection feature in my NordVPN app.
Working now.

You cannot use wire and uc_mode at a time.
ref: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/issues/2243
